# How to Update textfield onchange of dropdownlist without refresh page in Yii?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a Yii dropdownlist and text field, when i select the dropdown list item, this name should be displayed in textfield. I tried this concept using ajax with But it updates after page refresh  only.I have pasted my code here, please look-through and suggest me how to set
textfield after every immediate  selection of drop down listed item.

```
   The following code resides protected/views/form

    <td>    
    <?php echo $form->labelEx( ScriptQuestion::model(),'Field'); ?></td><td>
    <?php echo CHtml::activedropDownList( ScriptQuestion::model(),'crm_base_contact_form_field_id',$select_field,       
                array(
                'id' => 'send_bcfield',
                'class' => 'col_165',
                'ajax' => array(
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'url' => CController::createUrl('DisplayMessage'),                                                               
                    'update' => '#question_editor',
                    'data' => array('bcfield' => 'js:this.value'),
                    'success'=> 'function(data) {$("#question_editor").empty();
                            $("#question_editor").val(data);
                            } ',                    
                    ))      
    ); ?>               
    </td>
         <td>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'message', array('id'=>'question_editor','maxlength'=>508, )); ?>
           </td>
```

This is controller action:

```
    public function actionDisplayMessage(){ 
$q = $_POST['bcfield'];
$model=ScriptQuestion::model()->findAll();  
$sql = "SELECT name  FROM crm_field WHERE crm_field_id=". $q ;
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $result= $command->queryScalar(); 
    echo "%".$result."%";
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);       
    }
```

Comment: you must send the ajax request `onchange`

Comment: You mean onchange instead of success?

Comment: try alerting `data` in `success` part, and tell me what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to Ajax, it's just a simple **javascript/jQuery** .

Just do this ( replace editor1 with your ckeditor instance name) :

```
<script>
$("#send_bcfield").change(function(){
   var selected = $("#send_bcfield option:selected").val();
   CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(selected);
});
</script>
```

Or change your code to this :

```
<?php
echo CHtml::activedropDownList(ScriptQuestion::model(), 'crm_base_contact_form_field_id', $select_field, array(
    'id' => 'send_bcfield',
    'class' => 'col_165',
    'onchange' => '$("#send_bcfield").change(function(){
                    var selected = $("#send_bcfield option:selected").val();
                    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(selected);
                    });',
    )
);
?>
```

Update : I changed my code to **changing a ckeditor value** according to your comment below my answer.

Comment: I tried this but not works. this is also changed after page refresh. One thing  this text field id "question_editor" is integrated with CKEDITOR. Is this causes issue?

Comment: maybe, try putting a simple textarea with `id = 'question_editor'`

Comment: Yes, if i tried simple text area this get updated onselection of drop downlist item. But what can i do with ckeditor? Please help me to achieve this. I need to work this with ckeditor text area

Comment: what happened ? is ti okay dude ?

Comment: And one-thing how to update this ckeditor textarea. Now setData is cleared upon selection of next item. Instead i need to have both value in textarea

Comment: Yes i got it. if we use CKEDITOR.instances.question_editor.insertText(data); it get updated as per my previous comment

Comment: how to update value in a Yii textField? $("#question_editor").val(data); this line can set the value in textfield, instead i need to update onselection of every dropdownlist

Comment: `onchange` attribute of a `select` tag , is called when you select an option

Answer (score 1):

probably you simply need to add this to CHtml::activedropDownList settings:

```
  'onchange' => "$('question_editor').val($('#send_bcfield option:selected').text())"
```

Comment: I answered it exactly like you, but I read the last part of the question, I found out that OP doesn't want to show  the exact value of selectbox in textarea. he want to change it after a query and etc. and I deleted my answer

Comment: `when i select the dropdown list item, this name should be displayed in textfield.` if that is not true I am not sure what I should say

Comment: I know, he asked the question awefull, I undelete my answer